# SMTP mail - What could be possible reasons of Connection could not be established with host?

Tags: php, laravel, smtp

I am stuck through the day but couldn't find any solution for the error -

> Connection could not be established with host mail.mydomain.com [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known #0]

Following is my **.env** file -

```php
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.mydomain.com
MAIL_PORT=587 // tried 25 as well
MAIL_USERNAME=info@mydomain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=Password123
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=info@mydomain.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME='My App'
```

I have purchased domain from godaddy and hosted my app on host gator. I am not sure is there anything related to the MX record set I need to check?

What could be all possible reasons for this error? Please help me out.

Comment: Are you able to send email from command line?

Comment: How do you send your emails? Have you tried to send it via tinker, for example?

Comment: This seem to me to be something that would be documented in the GoDaddy help

Comment: Check out the default GoDaddy IMAP/SMTP settings here: https://nl.godaddy.com/help/smtp-outgoing-port-23885 and make sure to enable SSL and use the correct port.

Comment: I tried it with Gmail credentials and the same code is working fine.

Comment: if you are able to send email through command line then SMTP is working fine, you should now debug in your code

Comment: Actually, looking at the error it implies that it cannot find the domain you have entered: `mail.mydomain.com`. Try to check whether the CNAME has propagated with this tool: https://www.whatsmydns.net/

Comment: Something to check [on GoDaddy Help](https://uk.godaddy.com/community/VPS-Dedicated-Servers/Out-going-email-from-Laravel-application/td-p/107575)

Comment: @gerwin - when I checked CNAME, it shows red cross icon, it seems like something related to the CNAME, can you please let me know what should I check further?

Comment: Whoops, I meant `MX` for mail server. What happens if you do that?

Comment: I can ping `astonsanctuary.com` OK, but I cannot ping `mail.astonsanctuary.com` So this is definitely a DNS issue OR you are using the wrong name for the mail server

Comment: Also cannot ping `smtp.astonsanctuary.com`

Comment: @SachinVairagi Check out your DNS config in GoDaddy. You should have a valid record for the mail subdomain there. Maybe it's `imap`.

Comment: @gerwin No cannot ping `imap.` either

Comment: @gerwin You do not need to `@address` the OP asking the question. They get everything regardless

Comment: Here is my domain - astonsanctuary.com 
I have checked it on both sites - https://www.smtper.net/ and https://www.whatsmydns.net
Still not clear exactly what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`getaddrinfo failed` usually means that the host is not reachable from the machine.
Maybe you didn't configure your DNS for `mail.yourdomain.com` ?

You can try an email client (on the same machine) with the same credentials to see if it's able to send email, I guess it wil fail as well.